# Use navigation property or do separate queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have two entities. (I gave these entities as an example, in a real case they may have more different fields)

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get the id of the users whose organization isActive.

Option 1:

```
var userIds = await db.Users
    .Where(x => x.Organization.IsActive)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Option 2:

```
var organizationIds = await db.Organizations
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToListAsync();

var userIds = await db.Users
    .Where(x => organizationIds.Contains(x.OrganizationId))
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Probably a very banal question, but I always doubt what I should use in such a situation. Option 1 or option 2. Or does it depend, and if it depends on what and what to pay attention to?

Comment: depends ... pay attention to minimalize getting data from server ... in your example if there is no other need for organizationIds  then do not get it

Comment: Option 1 makes more sense to me, as you do not need to do two queries when you can do one query. In option 2, you can potentially supply too many IDs and may face some limitations

Comment: I will be really surprised if you need such a query without parameters. I
Do not think that you will need to fetch all the users

Comment: The correct way to decide what is better is to catch the plain SQL, execute it with counters, and analyze it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess about the case when the second approach will be executed faster. The main benefit of the first approach is that SQL can build the best execution plan to fetch the data you need. With the second approach, there may be a lot of pitfalls:

1. First of all, you will
   pass the `organizationIds` which can be huge.
2. Also you can have active organizations without users, so you will pass, so it's redundant to pass such organization IDs.
3. You have two calls to db and that is worse than one.
   The first approach is better. One call, sql server can optimize the query and you transfer the only data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the same things in essence. When we write option 1, behind the scenes, this query will be converting to the SQL join query, and the database engine under the hood, will convert the normal join queries to the separeted queries.

And when we write option 2, same as in the option 1, this will be executing as the 2 independent SQL queries for each table.

So I think, basically,these 2 LINQ queries will be executing as the same behind the scenes at the database layer.

Comment: Join is a single operation it will not be converted to two different Q. Also depends on data it may be executed in different ways

Comment: Do you mean, nested loop joins or some other thing?

Comment: It seems using Include() will be helpful, cause database engine optimizes the high level join quries as converting them to spesific forms.

Comment: Include has nothing to do with this case. It's Linq to Entities, not Linq to Objects. These queries are fully transformed into SQL text.  Include you can use only when you fetch the object that has navigation property but we do fetch here only IDs (list of int)

Comment: There are a few Algorithms that  SQL servers can choose to execute the JOIN operations. But the JOIN table with table provides more options to the server than the JOIN table to IDs.(1,2,3..)

Comment: Please see my answer for other concerns

Comment: @BasilKosovan We need to check whether Organization's isActive is true or not, so in this case we have to use include, we have to retrieve data from both table, via join.

Comment: Include is about retrieving. But we do retrieve only ids, so there is nothing to include

Answer (score 0):

option1 is correct way and if you want to get organizations in your object you can use include and get the organization data as well.